# how to find day name from given date for current year?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the birth date from particular year, i want to find the day name of that birth date for current year.

how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find birthdate in this year like;

```
var birthDate = new DateTime(1983, 10, 21);
var thisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, birthDate.Month, birthDate.Day);

var dayOfWeek = thisYear.DayOfWeek; // it gives you day of week of birth day in this year
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    string day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string Name = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
```

Hops its helps

Answer (score 0):

I use this Extension Method:

```
public static string GetDayName(this DateTime date)
{
    string _ret = string.Empty; //Only for .NET Framework 4.0++
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); //<- 'es-419' = Spanish (Latin America), 'en-US' = English (United States)
    _ret = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(date.DayOfWeek); //<- Get the Name     
    _ret = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(_ret.ToLower()); //<- Convert to Capital title
    return _ret;
}
```

Then we call it:

```
var birthDate = new DateTime(1983, 10, 21);
var thisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, birthDate.Month, birthDate.Day);

var dayOfWeek = thisYear.GetDayName(); //<- Returns 'Monday'
```